# How to use sscanf for longer string analysis

Tags: c, string

I just found a solution that convert a string of mac address to a array like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

char mac[] = "ff-13-a9-1f-b0-88";

unsigned char a[6];

sscanf(mac, "%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);

printf("%x,%x", *a, *(a+1));

}
```

This piece of code works ok and fits my needs. But what if I want to convert a long string like `ff-13-a9-1f-b0-88...(REPEAT 100 TIMES)...-ff-00` to char array?

Repeatedly write `%x-%x` in code is neither convenient nor elegant.

I do consider to use `memcpy` with a loop, but I just cannot copy half a byte(convert 0x0f, 0x0f to 0xff), right?

Comment: Although it may appear to work, the code shown has a number of problems. The most important is that there is a buffer overflow of the array because an unsigned int is being written to each entry of the unsigned char array. Also, it would only appear to work on little endian machines and would cause a misaligned write error on some processors. 
`sscanf(mac, "%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);`
should be:
`sscanf(mac, "%hhx-%hhx-%hhx-%hhx-%hhx-%hhx", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read one by one, and use `%n` at the end to get the count of characters consumed so far. I.e.

```
char *position = mac;
char separator;
int consumed = 0;

while (1) {
    int converted = sscanf(position, "%x%c%n", &one_number, &separator, &consumed);
    if (converted == 2) {
        if (separator == '-') {
            position += consumed;
        }
        else {
            // malformed string, separator wasn't -
        }
    }
    else if (converted == 1) {
        // last number
    }
    else {
        // none converted, scanf error. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `memcpy`, you can assign the values to build up the byte like this.

```
byte_value = lower_nibble + (higher_nibble<<4);
```

You use the `lower_nibble` as is, but shift the `higher_nibble` 4 places so that it becomes `0xf0` (or whatever value it is).

Used in a loop, you can shift the current byte value and then add on the current nibble (half-byte) and then reset it when you hit a non-hex digit

```
unsigned int byte_value=0;
char *pos
for(pos=mac;*pos!='\0';pos++)
  {
  if(isdigit(*pos))
    {
    byte_value <<= 4;
    byte_value += *pos-'0';
    }
  else if(isxdigit(*pos))
    {
    byte_value <<= 4;
    byte_value += tolower(*pos)-'a'+10;
    }
  else
    {
    printf("Byte is %x\n",byte_value);
    byte_value=0;
    }
  }
printf("Byte is %x\n",byte_value);
```

Comment: Oops about the mis-edit.

Comment: That's very helpful!! Thanks!